# smarty throwing error on using $smarty.post

Tags: php, smarty

We are using smarty as template system for one of our form, please check add/edit form code...

```
<form action="{$MAIN_URL}products/add" method="post" class="clearfix">
<input type="text" name="cname" value="{if $smarty.post.cname}{$smarty.post.cname}{elseif $editdetails.product_name}{$editdetails.product_name}{/if}" />
```

its throwing following error...

```
Undefined variable: post in <b>/root/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_data.php</b> on line 291
```

It works fine if we remove `{if $smarty.post.cname}{$smarty.post.cname}` please help to fix. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
{if isset($smarty.post) && isset($smarty.post.cname)}
```

but for the sake of brevity, this should work

```
{if isset($smarty.post.cname)}{$smarty.post.cname}{elseif $editdetails.product_name}{$editdetails.product_name}{/if}
```

Comment: thats okay, if it worked can you mark me as the answer please ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `{$smarty.post.cname}`, is your variable actually called `{$post.cname}`? You other `{$editdetails}` would seem to imply that.

This assumes that `$smarty` is the PHP Smarty object variable, and not a template variable.

Comment: we are using same form editing and adding data, so we are providing $editdetails as an array, so what should we update to make it fixed?